# Best option to store / retrieve thousand of data data from MySQL Don't block the main thread fast and efficient

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley, android-glide

I am creating an app which contains lots of data (images & text) from server but it take much time loading and some devices it shows black screen I think that it block the main thread  that's why. Any guidelines?
I am using String requests for retrieving data from server
for storing  I am using String request also with the help of Volley
Images take much time to display I am using Glide for showing images
App Performance is Slow not working smoothly

Thanks in Advance Guide Me..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Volley nor Retrofit is designed for large file downloads, and you will probably run into out-of-memory issues(seems like you already have).  I would use  DownloadManager instead of volley.

Here are some useful links:

https://codinginfinite.com/android-download-manager-example/

https://medium.com/@aungkyawmyint_26195/downloading-file-properly-in-android-d8cc28d25aca

Comment: Thanks but I am Loading data from server Download Manager can work fast and Smooth?